# Maximize $x^2+y^2+z^2$ subject to $x+2y+3z=4$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, lagrange-multiplier

> If $x+2y+3z=4$, then find maximum value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$, where $x,y,z\geq 0$.

**My try, using Lagrange multiplier method:**

$$x^2+y^2+z^2=\lambda(x+2y+3z)$$

So $\displaystyle 2x=\lambda$ and $2y=2\lambda$ and $2z = 3\lambda$

Put $\displaystyle x=\frac{\lambda}{2}\;\;,y=z\;\;,z=\frac{3}{2}$ in $x+2y+3z=4$. We get $\displaystyle \lambda = \frac{4}{7}$

So $$\displaystyle (x^2+y^2+z^2)_{\max} = \frac{164}{49}\;,$$ When $\displaystyle x=\frac{2}{7}\;\;,y=\frac{4}{7}\;\;,z=\frac{12}{7}$

Is my solution right? If not then how can we calculate it?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "then _find_ the maximum value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$"?

Comment: Yes abi maximum of $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: I think your answer is wrong - take $x= 4-2dl$ ;$2y=dl$; $3z=dl$ You get $x^2+y^2+z^2 = $ nearly $16$

Comment: The $\lambda$ is not right, and there is no reason to think it gives a maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After replacing the constraint $x$, $y$, $z>0$ by $x$, $y$ , $z\geq0$ the feasible domain becomes a closed triangle $T$ with its vertices on the positive coordinate axes. Imagine a sphere centered at $O$, so large that it contains the triangle $T$ in its interior. Now continually shrink this sphere until it hits one of the vertices of $T$. This will be the vertex $X:=(4,0,0)$, since the other vertices are lying nearer to $O$. It follows that the point of $T$ farthest away from $O$ is $X$, and that the maximum of the given function on $T$ is $4^2=16$.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum of this function occurs at the boundary. i.e, at $x=4, y=0, z=0$ . The maximum happens to be $16$.

If you wanted the minimum though, It occurs at $x=\frac 27; y=\frac 47; z=\frac 67$ The minimum is $\frac {56}{49}$ . It follows your own way, with a few corrections.

Comment: To win vineeth, how can we prove that maximum occur at boundry

Comment: To finish (or rather start) your argument, you need to show the objective function is convex, on a closed compact domain, which is true.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the product

$$
p=(x+2y+3z-4)(2x+y+6z+8)
$$

Expanding $p$, we have

$$
p=2x^2+2y^2+18z^2+5xy+12xz+15yz+12y-32 \geq 2x^2+2y^2+18z^2-32
$$

Since $p=0$, dividing by $2$ we deduce

$$
x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq x^2+y^2+9z^2 \leq 16
$$

Equality is when $x=2,y=z=0$.

Answer (score -1):

The choice of using Lagrange's multiplier is correct but your calculation seems a little correction i guess, you get  $$2x=\lambda$$$$2y=2\lambda$$$$2z=3\lambda$$
using these values you put $$x=\lambda/2$$$$y=\lambda$$$$z=3\lambda/2$$
putting these values in the constraint function you get $\lambda=4/7$
using these values you get $$x=2/7$$$$y=4/7$$$$z=12/14$$

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is clearly wrong. Put $y=z=0$ giving $x=4$, and $x^2+y^2+z^2=16$.

If $x+2y+3z=4$ then $x=4-2y-3z$. Substitute into $x^2+y^2+z^2$ giving
\begin{equation*}
5y^2+10z^2+12yz-16y-24z+16
\end{equation*}
as the function.

This has a MINIMUM value at $x=2/7, y=4/7, z=6/7$ using standard two-variable partial derivative methods. The maximum is unbounded.

Comment: The maximum is bounded, because $x,y,z$ are all bounded (from $x+2y+3z=4$)